# Detecting motion gestures with siri remote tvOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tvos, siri-remote

I am developing an app for tvOS and I want when the user shakes the remote, or moves it in a downward slash, that an event gets triggerred. But apple's documentation mostly focuses on registering button presses and the focus engine.

Can anyone help me with how I can access the accelometer?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the motion sensing aspects of the Siri Remote, you need to treat it as a game controller. See [Working with Game Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwithGameControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH18-SW1) in *App Programming Guide for tvOS* and the [GCMotion](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/GameController/Reference/GCMotion_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GCMotion) class.

Answer (score 0):

While it's fairly easy to port an ios game to tvos, note the following limitation that did slow me down as originaly I was using the rotation feature and expected to be the same on the remote, I had overlooked it in the doc but it says "*Although the remote supports motion data (and the GCMotion profile), the remote cannot determine the attitude or rotation of the remote. The corresponding properties always return constant values*."
And the constant values as per the tvOS header GCMotion.h are:

```
@note Remotes can not determine a stable rotation rate so the values will be (0,0,0) at all times.
@note Remotes can not determine a stable attitude so the values will be (0,0,0,1) at all times.
```